# Android : what kind of server?

Tags: android, http, tcp, server

I'm developing an android app where I would like to fetch some data (mostly text) from the internet but not necesseraly from a website! I would like to have a server that allows clients to fetch some text data. What kind of server fits my goals the best? Http or maybe simply tcp? I don't know much about http so I don't know if it matches my goals and/or if it handles well a kind of text "database".

Edit:
A use case could be: people could write comments and send them to the server. Then clients could refresh their app by fetching new comments from the server. Therefore I'M asking what kind of server could best handle services and kind offre database if needed.

Comment: If your data are not sensitive, you can use HTTP like a RESTful webservice. You are accessing a php page via HTTP requests in Android. It works well and it is pretty simple

Comment: You can use `Parse.com` as your back end.

Answer (score 0):

I like using NodeJS in combination with ExpressJS for such purposes. This combination allows you to easily work with HTTP/HTTTPS which is allowed by practically every firewall or proxy server. As of the latter reason I recommend you to use HTTP instead of an own protocol. Furhtermore, Java offers the HTTPURLConnection client which is very easy to use. Moreover, securing traffic with TLS (SSL) is very simple. In addition, NodeJS is resource efficient, runs on Windows, Linux and even on OS X.

For getting the text you can use HTTP GET request handled by the `get()` method of the Express instance.

[This compact tutorial](http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-create-rest-api) helped me to get familiar with Express on NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your use-case is it's difficult to make a good recommendation.

With that said you may find something like https://parse.com/ suitable.

They provide an Android sdk and the 'getting started' tutorials will have you up and running in no time at all.

Comment: A use case could be: people could write comments and send them to the server. Then clients could refresh their app by fetching new comments from the server. Therefore I'M asking what kind of server could best handle services and kind offre database if needed.